# firefox color management preferences

Tags: firefox, browser, jpeg, image-editing, color-profiles

the documentation of the Firefox gfx.color_management.mode preference refers to "tagged graphics" and "rendered graphics".  These terms are also found in many Mozilla development discussions, and also in some W3C discussions.  But what do they mean?  I could not find a clear definition.  When I change the value from 2 to 1 the colors for jpeg images change drastically.  Does that mean jpegs are "rendered graphics"?  They can have tags after all.  Any clarification welcome, thanks.

Comment: [Web browser color management guide](https://cameratico.com/guides/web-browser-color-management-guide/)

Comment: @DavidPostill that was one of the resources I read just before posting. I have a Dell wide-gamut monitor too, just as the author of that article.  I have profiled it, and when I set that profile in image processing and viewing software like RawTherapee and Geeqie, my images look just right in them.  They also look right in Firefox when I follow the recommendations of the article but everything else looks horrible , both images (from other sources) and HTML/CSS elements.  For instance pure blue, such as the one used for unvisited links with the default CSS, goes almost all the way to purple.